# Wondering how to do it with select insertion

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
INSERT INTO report (server_id, reported_id, reporting_id, admin_id)
            SELECT s.server_id, rep.reported_id, ru.reporting_id, a.admin_id
            FROM server s, reported_user rep, reporting_user ru, admin a
            WHERE s.server_port = 'port'
            AND rep.reported_steam_id = 'id'
            AND ru.reporting_steam_id = 'id'
            AND a.admin_id = '0'
```

As you see above I have a query which fetches information from other tables and inserts the into a table called report. My problem is that; reason is not a foreign key and I do not know how to make a query with lets say:

```
INSERT INTO report (server_id, reported_id, reporting_id, admin_id, reason)
            SELECT s.server_id, rep.reported_id, ru.reporting_id, a.admin_id
            FROM server s, reported_user rep, reporting_user ru, admin a
            WHERE s.server_port = 'port'
            AND rep.reported_steam_id = 'id'
            AND ru.reporting_steam_id = 'id'
            AND a.admin_id = '0',
            "TEST"; // <-- Does not work. Trying to insert a text string here.
```

Comment: for `reason` you suppose to add "Test" string right??

Comment: That is correct. All (server_id, reported_id, reporting_id and admin_id) is references to other tables, but "reason" isn't. Thats a column inside of the talbe "report"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
        INSERT INTO report (server_id, reported_id, reporting_id, admin_id, reason)
        SELECT s.server_id, rep.reported_id, ru.reporting_id, a.admin_id,"TEST"
        FROM server s, reported_user rep, reporting_user ru, admin a
        WHERE s.server_port = 'port'
        AND rep.reported_steam_id = 'id'
        AND ru.reporting_steam_id = 'id'
        AND a.admin_id = '0'
```